# How to unit test/mock GET query with filter param on the Microsoft Graph API

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have graph API method that take in a query and returns filtered User objects. My aim is to setup a mock and send a mocked request with a parameter. My question is simply, what is the appropriate way to mock and unit test this request in a repository pattern where the request gets called from the repository?

I have a repository method like this that calls graph api request method.

```
public List<TMUser> GetUsersByName(string param)
{
    return this.graphApi.GetUserByNameAsync(param).Result;
}
```

The method takes in a parameter and returns a matching list of users.

```
public async Task<IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage> GetUserByNameAsync(string param)
{
    return await this.appClient.Users
        .Request(this.queryOptions)
        .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
        .Filter($"startswith(DisplayName,'{param}') or startswith(GivenName,'{param}') or 
        startswith(Surname,'{param}') or startswith(Mail,'{param}')").Select(@$"
        Id,
        DisplayName,
        GivenName,
        Surname,
        Mail,
        OtherMails,
        CompanyName)
}
```

> This is how I mock the graph api method and assign it this.Users. All the users get returned without being filtered!

```
private readonly Mock<IGraphAPI> repositoryMockGraphAPI;

this.repositoryMockGraphAPI.Setup(api => 
api.GetUserByNameAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(this.Users);
```

This is my test method and don't really know how to go about mocking/unit it is, having tried different methods.

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetUsersByName()
{
    var displayName = "TestUser-" + 1;

    var users = this.b2CRepository.GetUsersByName(displayName);
}
```

Comment: Personally that looks like something i would not unittest. I would moq the Repository for users of the Repository. But the 2 methods you show are not unittest worthy by itself. That's something for an integration test against a real tenant.

Comment: Could you expand a bit more on why they are not necessary to unit test?

Comment: I didn't say it not necessary. Its just the gain of such a test  would be minimal or just not high enough for me so i would not do it. If you have fixed the behavior of the graph client via a mock what logic remains that you would test? Theres no parameter checking theres no exception handling or any other logic visible here. So besides some slim help in regression there is nothing that justifying a test in my eyes.

Comment: I am trying to test whether the mehod I wrote GetUserByNameAsync returns the correct list of users when given a filter input. GetUserByNameAsync('test-user-one'); returns a list of all users that have the property of test-user-one. And that nothing else gets returned.

Comment: Check this blog for how to unit test an action filter: https://makolyte.com/aspdotnet-core-how-to-unit-test-an-action-filter/